# Pagination with wp_pagenavi not working on custom page

Tags: pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I am having trouble with `wp_pagenavi` working on the start page using a custom query. It's working well on every standard template like category.php. But not on the homepage.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

        $args=query_posts(array(
          'post__not_in'=> array(419),
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page' => 10,
          'paged' => get_query_var('page'), ));

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
       $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );

        $s1=strtolower($title);

       ?>
    <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" <?php $item_format = is_video() ? 'video' : 'post'; post_class('item cf item-'.$item_format); ?>>
        <div class="thumb">
        <?PHP '<a class="clip-link" data-id="'.$post->Id.'" title="'.esc_attr(get_the_title($post->Id)).'" href="'.get_permalink($post->Id).'">'?>
             <a class="clip-link"  title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark">
                <span class="clip">
                    <?php echo'<img src="'.$featuredImage.'" alt="'.esc_attr(get_the_title($post->Id)).'" />';?>
                    <span class="vertical-align"></span> 
                </span>

                <span class="overlay"></span>
            </a>
        </div><!--- thumb----->
    </div><!-- end #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

    <?php

     endwhile;
     global $my_query;
     $total_pages = $my_query->max_num_pages; 

         if($total_pages > 1)
         { ?>
                <div class="loop-nav pag-nav">
                <div class="loop-nav-inner">
                    <?php 
                    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
                        wp_pagenavi();
                    } else {
                        $label = __('&laquo; Prev', 'dp');
                        if($prev = get_previous_posts_link($label))
                            echo str_replace('<a', '<a clas="prev"', $prev);
                        else
                            echo '<span class="prev">'.$label.'</span>';

                        $label = __('Next &raquo;', 'dp');
                        if($next = get_next_posts_link($label))
                            echo str_replace('<a', '<a class="next"', $next);
                        else
                            echo '<span class="next">'.$label.'</span>';
                    } ?>
                </div>
                </div><!-- end .loop-nav -->
    <?php
 } 
    }

      wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>
            </div><!---nag cf---->
            </div><!---loop-content grid-mini--->
```

The pagination shows up, but the url `/page/2/` is not working, it shows `/page/1/` result.

Comment: Is this code used on a homepage, not a front page. And do you need to exclude post 419 from the loop

Comment: ya this is my theme home page and i want to exclude 419 post its sticky post

Comment: You are using `query_posts()`, which overrides the main query. Does the problem persist if you switch it for `new WP_Query( ... )` or `get_posts( ... )`?

Answer (score 0):

Your construction of your custom loop is a bit of a mess unfortuantely. I'm not going to go through this now, but I'll add links for you to go and read through :-).

You should go and have a look on how to properly construct a custom query with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You should also have a read about using the [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) when using a custom query. The last point here, there are a few bugs in your code which you need to take a look at. You should set you debug to true in wp-config.php. Here is an article about [Debugging Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

At this point in time, you are only creating a custom query to remove one post from the loop. Apart from that, you are running the main query in a custom loop.

**Here is how I would tackle this problem.**

Reset your page with the standard loop, the same loop you've used that said is working on category.php. Now, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to exclude your post from the main query. Here is the code. Add this in functions.php. This is modified from the codex.

```
function exclude_single_posts_home($query) {
    if ($query->is_home() AND $query- >is_main_query()) {
         $query->set('post__not_in', array(419));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_posts_home');
```